# Get code between php tags with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get php code out of a HTML template file to execute it and place the result back.
What regular expression code can I use? And is there a method that also return the position of the found first tag?

```
<p>some html</p>

<?php $some = "php code"; ?>

<p>some <em>more</em> html</p>

<?php $some = "more php code"; ?>
```

I want the php code filtered from the html.

Comment: HTML isn't a regular language, so you need to use an HTML parser which is more powerful than just a regular expression.

Comment: I would look for the "<?" and "?>"

Comment: It's easier to provide a good answer if you include some example code. Give us an example of a template file, and tell us what language you are using to try to parse it.

Comment: HTML parser can't parse out the PHP code.

Comment: How is this done with a regular expression? It would be nice If the result was an array with al the filtered php code

Comment: Here's a regular expression `<\?.*?\?>`

Comment: @Jack this expression returns the code with out the '<' '>' chars `echo $parts = preg_match("<\?.*?\?>",$output,$matches);`

Comment: That's cause you're using the `<` and `>` as delimiters.  You need to do `preg_match("/<\?.*?\?>/",$output,$matches);` and use `/` as a delimiter.

Comment: @jack when the code is not on the same (has more) line there's no result. What is  the problem?

Comment: You need to set the multiline flag.  Use this `preg_match("/<\?.*?\?>/m",$output,$matches)` or `preg_match("/<\?.*?\?>/s",$output,$matches)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/<\?.*?\?>/m",$output,$matches)
```

or

```
preg_match("/<\?.*?\?>/s",$output,$matches)
```

Should match all lines.

Comment: Doesn't works if you have '?>' in string or comment, example:`<? $b = '?>';
$c = '';
$d = '';
$e = '';
$a = 1;
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "getting the PHP out and putting it back" you should pass the variables to the template file.

**Something like this:**

```
<?php 
function loadTemplate($path,$data=array()){
    if (file_exists($path) === false){
        throw new Exception('Template not found:'.$path);
        return false;
    }

    extract($data);
    ob_start();
    require($path);
    $return = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $return;
}

$vars = array('var1'=>$value,
              'var2'=>$somevalue,
              'var3'=>$someothervalue,
              'var4'=>$blab);

$template = loadTemplate('path/to/thefile.php',$vars);
?>
```

Then access the `$vars` array values from within **thefile.php** like
`echo $var1`
`echo $var2`
ect

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I away thought using `ob_start();` was a bad habit?

Comment: if you look at most MVC frameworks or template classes work they use this same method. even codeigniter within its main `_ci_load()` method

Comment: Ok thank you, this is an interesting approach, I'll dive in to it.

Comment: This wasn't the answer on my question but a way better approach for my situation. Thank you very much!